# CPU utilization report for multiple servers - Python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to get ps -aux command output for multiple servers in a excel or csv format. Output needs to be printed for the servers in different sheets. I'm unable to do that. Can someone help me on this by completing this script.

```
import paramiko
import subprocess
import json
import csv

with open(r'filepath\serverlist.json') as f:
data=json.load(f)


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
target_host = txt
un = 'root'
pwd = 'xxx'
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=target_host,username=un,password=pwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ps -aux')
```

Expected output as below for a server and it requires to be saved in different sheet for each server.

[image]

Comment: Use `Pandas` and you can define `sheet_name`. Convert your `stdout`  to a dataframe. If you add sample of `stdout`, I can help you more.

Comment: A sample of the output below

Filesystem          Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

devtmpfs            devtmpfs  697M     0  697M   0% /dev

tmpfs               tmpfs     713M     0  713M   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs               tmpfs     713M  9.1M  704M   2% /run

tmpfs               tmpfs     713M     0  713M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup,

Comment: Please edit in question as it doesn't look clear in comment